# What are the repercussions of giving chems to Mama Murphy?

Tags: fallout-4

Mama Murphy hangs out in Sanctuary, in the chair I built her, and asks me for chems so she can see the future. I happily obliged and gave her everything she asked for. As a result,

> She died of a heart attack. The settler count in Sanctuary decreased by one, and the other settlers were pretty bummed out.

Are there any further gameplay consequences, such as quests that won't be completable? Or do I just have to deal with my own moral repugnancy?

Comment: You have to endure [`Marcy Long`](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Marcy_Long)'s excessive nagging. Might not sound that bad but, trust me, it will drive you insane. Worst of all, you can't kill her, so tread lightly...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to deal with the fact that she died.

You missed "if Preston or (reformed) Cait are close by they *really* dislike your actions" (not tested with others but I imagine most of them would) off your list of consequences in the instance you kill her.

There are upsides and downsides to being her supplier, if you supply her all the way up to the point where she asks for Psycho she won't die. Each time you complete a mission with her you'll gain experience. As long as you haven't killed her you have the option to get her to quit.

The repercussions of not giving her chems and instead convincing her to quit are that you don't get to use her wonderful psychic abilities, which do strangely include bits and pieces of information that allow you to avoid a couple of encounters that occur during the game.

Comment: Codsworth also strongly dislikes anything chem-related, which includes supplying Mama Murphy. If you leave him in Sanctuary when supplying her, you'll get a big dislike every chem you give her. If you haven't already received his perk, you'll have to dig yourself out of some bad reputation right off the bat.

Comment: Her psychic abilities let you get past two main quest fights without fighting. i wouldn't call that pointless.

Comment: oh right yeah she tells you about the thing with the people in the place...

Answer (score -2):

Oooooh boy, I know it's been a while, but let me share some of my experience about this wonderful woman. Now I know this is a bit off, but Mama Murphy can help you avoid encounters with other unsavory "nouns" as well, so you should see a max difficulty on average for threatening or convincing her to get off the chems off the bat. She'll help you out, but making her keep her word to not go on the chems for her is really no different then her dying, so you will probably get a Super mutant posse from her that will come attack you because the sight is "dead" even though Murphy will not die from chems. This is how you can be sure that you're ready for a life without the sight.

As for Cait, if you complete her personal adventures, she ends up being no different from Piper in regards to your relationship in getting Murphy off of the chems, just in regards to who Piper is after she first offers to leave Diamond City with you.

Should really watch where you're walking. I went there to impress my chem free Cait, and Murphy was so mad she had to quit because I persuaded her off the chems she sent Super mutants after me when I walked back to my settlement at Red Rocket. It was only a day in game, and I had been there at Red Rocket for a week and a half with nothing going on. Guess she fell for the bad boy. XD